# Basic regular expression using eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

this is a really basic question, sorry!

So i have this text file in eclipse, with these contents:

```
6
20
42
75
76
105
119
159
164
170
172
```

and *all* i want to do is put this string in front of them

```
this.id ==
```

now, i hate regex like most people who know nothing about it, but i thought that if i searched for "^" and then replaced with "this.id ==" i'd be fine. I am not, however, fine.

So, the question:

using eclipse's ctrl-f feature, and with the regular expression box checked, how do i replace the text aboe with the this.id == in the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Find field, enter
    `([0-9]+)`

In the Replace with field, enter
    `this.id == $1`

Then click Replace All.

Answer (score 1):

Search for:

^(\d+)$

replace with

this.id == $1